# Explain: Limits, If You Actually Reach the second Point, you'd only have One point left

Tags: calculus

[image]

Want exact slope of parabola y=x(squared) at point (1,1)

Can someone please explain this: "If it did, you'd only have one point left and you need two separate points to use the slope formula".

Here is the paragraph:

With the slope formula from algebra, you can figure the slope of the line between (1,1) and (2,4).  From (1,1) to (2,4), you go over 1 and up 3, so the slope is 3/1, or just 3.  But you can see from image that this line is steeper than the tangent line at (1,1) that shows the parabola's steepness at that specific point.  The limit process sort of lets you slide the point that starts at (2,4) down toward (1,1) till it's a thousandth of an inch away, then a millionth, then a billionth, and so on down to the microscopic level.  If you do the math, 2.001, 2.000001, 2.000000001, and so on.  And with the almost magical mathematics of limits, you can conclude that the slope at (1,1) is precisely 2, even though the sliding point never reaches (1,1).  (If it did, you'd only have one point left and you need two separate points to use the slope formula.)

Comment: You don't need limits to calculate the slope of a tangent to a quadratic function. You also don't need two points. Just the desired point (point of tangency) is enough in case of a quadratic function.

Comment: What's the source of this text?

Comment: Calculus for dummies-can you please just answer the specific question, as to what is meant by the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slope of a line through two points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ is given by $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$, provided that $x_1\not=x_2$. If the two points happen to be the same point (i.e. $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$), then the formula does not make sense as you will have to divide by zero.